# Extract only few columns from a .dat file

Tags: c++, extract, multiple-columns, getline, istringstream

I've to make a program with c++ for my thesis that open and extract only two columns from a file .dat that is like this, with a lot of lines:

0.000000    -9.833374   1.000000    0.156921    0.125478    0.350911
5.015625    -9.831743   1.000000    0.157021    0.125752    0.349945
10.015625   -9.838824   1.000000    0.157101    0.125566    0.351512

I've obtained to open and read each lines with the command getline(), but i have no idea of how to extract only the columns that i need (in particular the second and the fourth).
I am a very beginner using this programming language, so can somebody give me examples or indications of how to obtain this task?

Thank you very much

Comment: See [Split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c) for examples of how you could extract the values from each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stringstream` for this:

```
ifstream file("data.dat")
string line;

while (getline(file,line))
{
    istringstream ss(line);

    // possibly you will want some other types here.
    string col2;  
    string col4;

    ss >> col2;    // extracts 1st col.
    ss >> col2;    // extracts 2nd col.

    ss >> col4;    // extracts 3rd col.
    ss >> col4;    // extracts 4th col.

    // Now you can something with col2 and col4
    cout << col2 << " " << col4 << endl;

}
```

Note that first I extract the first column to `col2` and then overwrite it with the second column. I do it analogously for `col4`.

Of course you can use other **types** for `col2` and `col4`, as long as this is consistent over your file.

Also if you do **not** want to read in columns, just to throw them away afterwards have a look at `std::istream::ignore`, which let's you skip over input.

Comment: So using this syntax (col1 and col2) my program understand automatically that i'm relating to the first and second column of the .dat file?

Comment: @PaoloOrsatti No!  the identifiers make no difference. The `>>` operator will simply read in one column each time it is called. so calling  `ss >> col;` two times will read in the first column to col and then the second column to the **same variable** (overwriting the first column stored before)

Comment: Thank you very much! You solved my problem, now i can extract the column that i want.

Comment: Now i have another problem: i have to comparate a data of the n-line of a column, with the data of the (n+1)line of the same column. Solutions?

Comment: @PaoloOrsatti you're welcome. Having this problem solved you should create a **new** question for your **new problem** ;)